# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'view'(1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, enumerate

My code is below and my problem is at `input_gray = input_gray.view(batch_size,1,64,32)`. Since I used enumerate I guess got a problem but don't know how to fix it, I need your help, thanks.

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Train for one epoch, then validate
    train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
    correct=0
    total=0

    with torch.no_grad():
        losses = validate(val_loader, model, criterion, save_images, epoch)
        for data in enumerate(train_loader):
            input_gray, labels = data
            input_gray = input_gray.view(batch_size,1,64,32)
            input_gray = input_gray.float()

        if use_gpu:
            input_gray, labels = input_gray.to.cuda(), labels.to.cuda()

        output_ab = model(input_gray)
        _, predicted = torch.max(output_ab.data,1)
        total+=labels.size()
        correct+=(predicted==labels).sum().item()

    print("Accuracy train %d %%"%(100*correct/total))
    train_acc.append(100*correct/total)    

    # Save checkpoint and replace old best model if current model is better   
    if losses < best_losses:
        best_losses = losses
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'checkpoints/model-epoch-{}-losses-{:.3f}.pth'.format(epoch+1,losses))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you enumerate a list, you get each item and its index returned as tuple `(index,item)`.

```
class something:
    def __init__(self,prop1,prop2):
        self.prop1=prop1
        self.prop2=prop2

l = [something(1,"a"),something(2,"b")]


for k in enumerate(l):
    index, data = k              # so k is a tuple of (index,item) - you can deref it

    print(index)                 

    # you can access the items properties like so:
    print(data.prop1, data.prop2)
```

Output:

```
0
1 a
1
2 b
```

Your code probably needs:

```
for data in enumerate(train_loader):
     index, (input_gray, labels) = data
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace with this line:

`for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):`

or with this line, if you do not need an index:

`for data in train_loader:`

Comment: actually i did it before but got another issue like "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"